# Data appears in API call but undefined when it's called

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So for my page I perform 2 API calls when the page first loaded, data is readable to some extent I will provide examples below.

For context I have an Activity API call and Players API call, the players API call works fine returns the things I need, I also call the Activity API so I can match the data from there with players (to show the relation between the two).

Here is where it's getting confusing

```
{
  "records": [
      {
          "recordId": 1,
          "bestePrestatie": "1,68m",
          "categorie": "Hoogspringen",
          "deelnemerId": 1,
          "disciplinedId": 0
      }
  ],
  "activiteiten": [
      {
          "deelnemerId": 1,
          "activiteitId": 2
      }
  ],
  "clubId": 1
}
```

When I try to call `activiteiten.deelnemerId` it works and I can use it on my page but when I try to call `activiteiten.activiteitId` it returns undefined for some reason despite them being in the same category

My initial use for these api calls is to compare the `players.activityId` with the `Activity.activityId`

```
assignMeth() {
  for (let speler of this.Players) {
    for (let acts of this.Act) {
      if (acts.activiteitId === this.actsvc.GetActID()) {
        this.orderList.push(speler);
        this.DataAvailable = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My first loop goes through because the data there is readable but once it reaches the 2nd loop it doesn't work anymore because the data I'm comparing is undefined.

EDIT: here is the class where I call the api with

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataserviceService } from '../dataservice.service';
import { RealDataService} from '../real-data.service';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { ActiviteitService, Activiteiten, Spelers } from '../activiteit.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deelnemers',
  templateUrl: './deelnemers.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deelnemers.page.scss'],
})
export class DeelnemersPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private actsvc: ActiviteitService, private realdata: RealDataService) {
    this.callPlayers();
    this.callAct();
    this.assignMeth();
  }

  newListTest = [];

  Act: Activiteiten[];
  Players: Spelers[];
  DataAvailable = false;
  orderList = [];

  ngOnInit() {


    this.callAct();
    this.callPlayers();


  }

  callAct() {
    return this.actsvc.GetAct().subscribe(g => {
      this.Act = g;
      console.log(this.Act);
    });
  }

  callPlayers() {
    return this.actsvc.GetSpelers().subscribe(g => {
      this.Players = g;
      this.DataAvailable = true;
      console.log(this.Players);
    });
  }



  assignMeth() {
    for (let speler of this.Players) {
      for (let acts of this.Act) {
        if (acts.activiteitId === this.actsvc.GetActID()) {
          this.orderList.push(speler);
          this.DataAvailable = true;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Post the methods with your api call

Comment: @jcmendes98 `  callAct() {
    return this.actsvc.GetAct().subscribe(g => {
      this.Act = g;
      console.log(this.Act);
    });
  }

  callPlayers() {
    return this.actsvc.GetSpelers().subscribe(g => {
      this.Players = g;
      this.DataAvailable = true;
      console.log(this.Players);
    });
  }`

Comment: Create a class, make the array of that class. then atribute the api call value, to the array.

Comment: Post, the method on the question not on comments, and add more code, as type of variables etc.

Comment: I edited the post to include the full class